# Why am I getting a Type Error, when I was not getting one previously for the same command?

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I have been working through a python for data science/machine learning class on udemy. Working on Linear Regression problems, when examining the data set I am attempting to do a distplot for the Price column,but I get an incomplete dist plot with no KDE line.
Previously I would run following line of code and would get a dist plot with KDE KDE line, unless I changed the parameter to False.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sklearn
import seaborn as sns 
%matplotlib inline

USAhousing = pd.read_csv('USA_Housing.csv')
sns.distplot(USAhousing['Price'])
```

Recently installed scipy, updated sci-kit learn.Now I am getting an error

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-11-9e41d9931423> in <module>()
    ----> 1 sns.distplot(USAhousing['Price'])

    C:\Users\Edric\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\distributions.py in distplot(a, bins, hist, kde, rug, fit, hist_kws, kde_kws, rug_kws, fit_kws, color, vertical, norm_hist, axlabel, label, ax)
        219     if kde:
        220         kde_color = kde_kws.pop("color", color)
    --> 221         kdeplot(a, vertical=vertical, ax=ax, color=kde_color, **kde_kws)
        222         if kde_color != color:
        223             kde_kws["color"] = kde_color

    C:\Users\Edric\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\distributions.py in kdeplot(data, data2, shade, vertical, kernel, bw, gridsize, cut, clip, legend, cumulative, shade_lowest, ax, **kwargs)
        602         ax = _univariate_kdeplot(data, shade, vertical, kernel, bw,
        603                                  gridsize, cut, clip, legend, ax,
    --> 604                                  cumulative=cumulative, **kwargs)
        605 
        606     return ax

    C:\Users\Edric\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\distributions.py in _univariate_kdeplot(data, shade, vertical, kernel, bw, gridsize, cut, clip, legend, ax, cumulative, **kwargs)
        268         x, y = _statsmodels_univariate_kde(data, kernel, bw,
        269                                            gridsize, cut, clip,
    --> 270                                            cumulative=cumulative)
        271     else:
        272         # Fall back to scipy if missing statsmodels

    C:\Users\Edric\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\distributions.py in _statsmodels_univariate_kde(data, kernel, bw, gridsize, cut, clip, cumulative)
        326     fft = kernel == "gau"
        327     kde = smnp.KDEUnivariate(data)
    --> 328     kde.fit(kernel, bw, fft, gridsize=gridsize, cut=cut, clip=clip)
        329     if cumulative:
        330         grid, y = kde.support, kde.cdf

    C:\Users\Edric\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\nonparametric\kde.py in fit(self, kernel, bw, fft, weights, gridsize, adjust, cut, clip)
        144             density, grid, bw = kdensityfft(endog, kernel=kernel, bw=bw,
        145                     adjust=adjust, weights=weights, gridsize=gridsize,
    --> 146                     clip=clip, cut=cut)
        147         else:
        148             density, grid, bw = kdensity(endog, kernel=kernel, bw=bw,

    C:\Users\Edric\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\nonparametric\kde.py in kdensityfft(X, kernel, bw, weights, gridsize, adjust, clip, cut, retgrid)
        504     zstar = silverman_transform(bw, gridsize, RANGE)*y # 3.49 in Silverman
        505                                                    # 3.50 w Gaussian kernel
    --> 506     f = revrt(zstar)
        507     if retgrid:
        508         return f, grid, bw

    C:\Users\Edric\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\nonparametric\kdetools.py in revrt(X, m)
         18     if m is None:
         19         m = len(X)
    ---> 20     y = X[:m/2+1] + np.r_[0,X[m/2+1:],0]*1j
         21     return np.fft.irfft(y)*m
         22 

    TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method
```

I use to get the graph as expected, now I am getting an incomplete graph with the aforementioned Type Error. I realize that this may be an easy, fundamental fix. Being new to Python and Data Science as it relates to Python it is hard to discern what that might be. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had similar a problem, updating underlying `statsmodels` resolved the issue for me.
try updating it:

```
pip install -U statsmodels
```

or for anaconda

```
conda update statsmodels
```